# JQuery click() won't apply to anchor tag?

Tags: click, jquery

I am creating some thumbnails dynamically with JQuery, like this (in a loop):

```
var thumb = $('<a class="tinythumb"></a>');
thumb.append('<img src="' + productThumbnailList[i] + '" width="70" height="70" />');
thumbContainer.append(thumb);
```

Now I'm trying to add some functionality to these via JQuery's `.click()`, but I just can't get it working. I've never had trouble trying to do this before, there are no errors and there's nothing that I can see from my point of view that is incorrect.

I tried this simple `.each()` to see what would happen. Funnily enough, the `rel` attribute **is** being updated, but there's still no `.click()` functionality (alert never performed).

```
$("div#thumbcontainer a").each(function()
{
    $(this).attr("rel", "works");
    $(this).click(function()
    {
        alert('never called');

    });
});
```

This is the page I'm trying to work with:

http://burwell.businesscatalyst.com/catalogue/containmentscreen/Enviroguard#

---

Here's the entire JavaScript which probably has something relevant in it that's missing above:

```
// Properties
var thumbContainer = $("div#thumbcontainer");
var str = thumbContainer.html();
var productThumbnailList = str.split(';');

// Clear thumbContainer of junk HTML
thumbContainer.html("");


// Create thumbnails
if(productThumbnailList.length > 1)
{
    for(var i = 0; i<productThumbnailList.length; i++)
    {
        var large = Math.round(i/2) * 2 == i ? false : true;

        // create thumbnail
        if(!large)
        {
            var thumb = $('<a class="tinythumb"></a>');
            thumb.append('<img src="' + productThumbnailList[i] + '" width="70" height="70" />');
            thumbContainer.append(thumb);
        }
    }

    $("div#thumbcontainer a").each(function()
    {
        $(this).attr("rel", "works");
        $(this).click(function()
        {
            alert('never called');

        });

    });
}
```

---

Adding an `onclick="someFunc()"` parameter to the `<a>` tag makes it call the function fine..

Comment: Can I use any image from your website in the JSFiddle to demonstrate the working solution? I don't have any image available online to use.

Comment: Please check now. http://jsfiddle.net/SUudh/7/

Comment: @JQone Yeah so that works but it doesn't on my site. Must be something to do with the way that I'm generating the thumbnails maybe..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating the anchor tag dynamically, use "on" to attach click event handler

```
$('#thumbContainer').on("click","a", function(){ 
  alert("will work now"); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SUudh/23/

If you are using older version of jquery, use live() or delegate().

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: no, jQuery introduced "on" function in 1.7+ see it here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @JQone I've given this a go but it hasn't helped. What's strange is that another dynamically created button works fine with a `.click()` attached to it.

Comment: @JQone Didn't help. Really strange.

Comment: JsFillde - http://jsfiddle.net/SUudh/2/             Can you and image tag inside the anchor and check if it works?

Comment: This is not the correct syntax for handling delegated events with `.on`

Answer (score 1):

you dont have to attach the click handler in the `each` loop try [**delegate**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (out side the loop ofcourse)

```
$("div#thumbcontainer").delegate("a","click",function(e){
        alert('never called'); /should be called

    });
```

Comment: True on the first point - that was more just to test if the items were being selected properly and such (hence the `.attr("rel", "works")`). This didn't work either..

Answer (score 0):

there is a syntax error in your code add ) to end of code

```
$("div#thumbcontainer a").each(function()
{
    $(this).attr("rel", "works");
    $(this).click(function()
    {
        alert('never called');

    });
})
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo in the question when I shortened and made relevant the question. Nice pickup though.

Comment: so where are you calling your code? in document.ready function?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on#direct-and-delegated-events) with jQuery is to use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on). Basically, when you add elements dynamically, they don't yet actually exist at the time you bind the handler. So instead you bind the function to a static ancestor element of the new one — one which *does* exist when you're binding the handler, and let the event 'bubble' up, and handle it there.

Code-wise, this is what you end up doing:

*Get rid of all of this.*

```
$("div#thumbcontainer a").each(function()
{
    $(this).attr("rel", "works");
    $(this).click(function()
    {
        alert('never called');
    });
});
```

Replace it with this.

```
// $('#thumbcontainer a').attr('rel', 'works'); chain this directly if needed

$("#thumbcontainer").on('click', 'a', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the click from following link
    alert('this gets called!');
});
```